# Write string conditional assigning into new column as one linear or in a more concise manner

Tags: python, pandas

I am wondering if there's a way to write the string conditional assigning method in a more concise way.

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
from sklearn import datasets
wine = pd.DataFrame(datasets.load_wine().data)
wine.columns = datasets.load_wine().feature_names

conditions = [(wine.hue > 1), (wine.hue == 1), (wine.hue < 1)]
status = ['A', 'B', 'C']
wine['status_label'] = np.select(conditions, status)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can use list comprehension !

```
win_hue = [1, 2, -5, 0, -9, 4, 10, 1, -9, 8]

wine_status = [((wh < 1)*'A' + (wh == 1)*'B' + (wh > 1)*'C') for wh in win_hue]

In [1]: wine_status
Out[1]: ['B', 'C', 'A', 'A', 'A', 'C', 'C', 'B', 'A', 'C']
```